# How to wrap interface properties with FormGroup and FormArray

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  phones: Phone[];
}
```

And I want to convert those properties to FormGroup if it's not an array, or FormArray if it is an array (like phones in this example).
I tried creating an interface like this

```
export type GenericFormModel<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends [] ? AbstractControl<T[K]> : FormControl<T[K] | null>;
};
```

but it just doesn't work, typescript still thinks **phones** is a FormGroup, but it should be a FormArray. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are checking the `K extends []`, where `K` is just a key : `'name' | 'age' | 'phones'`. What you should check instead is the value under the key `K`. Another issue is that you are checking against `[]`, which is empty tuple and it is going to be true only if the value is `[]` as well. Instead check against `unknown[]`.

```
type GenericFormModel<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]> extends unknown[]
    ? AbstractControl<T[K]>
    : FormControl<T[K] | null>;
};
```

Comment: Still getting the same error if the field is optional, tried using never but it didnt work

Comment: can you include a playground link?

Comment: @matthew I have updated the answer; please update the OP as well, since the properties are required in there